# How to extract features from a pytorch pretrained fine-tuned model

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I need to extract features from a pretrained (fine-tuned) BERT model.

I fine-tuned a pretrained BERT model in Pytorch using huggingface transformer. All the training/validation is done on a GPU in cloud.

At the end of the training, I save the model and tokenizer like below:

```
best_model.save_pretrained('./saved_model/')
tokenizer.save_pretrained('./saved_model/')
```

This creates below files in the `saved_model` directory:

```
config.json
added_token.json
special_tokens_map.json
tokenizer_config.json
vocab.txt
pytorch_model.bin
```

I save the `saved_model` directory in my computer and load the `model` and `tokenizer` like below

```
model = torch.load('./saved_model/pytorch_model.bin',map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('./saved_model/')
```

Now to extract features, I do below

```
input_ids = torch.tensor([tokenizer.encode("Here is some text to encode", add_special_tokens=True)])
last_hidden_states = model(input_ids)[0][0]
```

But for the last line, it throws me error `TypeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable`

It seems like I am not loading the model properly. Instead of loading the entire model in itself, I think my `model=torch.load(....)` line is loading a ordered dictionary.

What am I missing here? Am I even saving the model in the right way? Please suggest.

Comment: Try `model.load_state_dict(torch.load('./saved_model/pytorch_model.bin', map_location=torch.device('cpu')))`

Answer (score 1):

[torch.load()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=load#torch.load) returns a `collections.OrderedDict` object. Checkout the [recommended way](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#saving-loading-model-for-inference) of saving and loading a model's state dict.

**Save**:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

**Load**:

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

So, in your case, it should be:

```
model = BertModel(config)
model.load_state_dict('./saved_model/pytorch_model.bin',
                       map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
model.eval() # to disable dropouts
```

Comment: When I follow this approach of saving the model, PATH is a filename right? If it is a directory, I get an error. And in this approach, there is no `config.json` created. So the loading does not work.